# Is it possible to define CSS media query max-width relatively via % in WinJS?

Tags: css, media-queries, winjs, windows-8.1

I'd like to know whether it is possible to do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 50%) {}
```

(Note: the snippet above won't work because max-width expects `<Length>`)

I already tried `max-width: calc(50%)` but had no luck.

Is there a way to do this with only CSS in WinJS, or will I have to do it with Javascript on layout change?

**Update:**
See answer below. This is how you can do it for approx. 50%. But what if I want different values, such as 25%? Is there a solution?

Comment: This is to see if someone uses half of it's screen to browse?

Comment: Yes, for snap-view state. Because the app itself will scale to exactly the same for each resolution and having a definite amount of px for max-width would result in different looking snap-view for different resolutions.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem being solved here.  If my resolution is 1024x768 but my browser's viewport is 800x600, why wouldn't the same styles apply to it as styles for a fullscreen browser running at 800x600 resolution?

Comment: @cimmanon they definitely would apply to that resolution. But I'm currently developing a Win8-Application which will look the same on each resolution, because of appropriate scalingfactor. If I calculate max-width with let's say 400px and I'm on a 27'' monitor, the style will first apply if the app is snapped to the very left side of the monitor. And hence the content of the app is still fully scaled, it would look crappy. So I'd like to have that style applied at half of the screen. - Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: In CSS, you could certainly have 2 different width checks `@media (max-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)`, but this will get quite messy.  Just keep in mind that there's no way to determine the physical size of your monitor (ie. there's no difference between 21" and 27" if they're both displaying at the same resolution as far as the OS can tell).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure with it's for, but I think portrait view can help you out in most desktop browse scenarios.

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
   .. styles
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great - it works! This would have never come to my mind, because I always thought the orientation is bound to device orientation in W8-Apps!

Comment: @malte Ah no, you can safely use that anywhere, mobile, tablet, desktops.. I think every platform got it covered by now.

Comment: In browsers I'd have agreed with you at first glance, but it was new for me that Windows8-Apps with HTML/JS behave the same way :)